# How to open files with whitespaces in the terminal?

Tags: terminal

I'm trying to execute a flex and bison file in Command Prompt but I get the following error:-

[image]

I know this is because the file has whitespace in their name( Program Files and Program Files (x86).

I am not allowed to change the name of these files. As suggested by other Stack Overflow answers I can't use quotation marks in the file name because I am not using the file name directly. I tried to edit the file path in the environment variables with quotation marks(that's where this file location is getting used and hence the error). but that doesn't seem to help.

Please suggest a solution for the error. I have tried to fix it for more than two hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get away with the error myself. It's not hard. You just need to move your GnuWin32 folder to some other location which doesn't have a space or parenthesis and make it an environment variable.

Comment: you should use `\ ` for spaces